# Python Formating and calculating with numbers of a string (list)

Tags: python, formatting, calculation

Currently coding a little "beginner" problem which is able to calculate the Area of a triangle ABC based on the coordinates (x,y) of each point that are defined by the users input.

I already did some calculation and as long as I declare the values of each point manually there is no problem:

```
px1, px2, px3, py1, py2, py3 = [0,-2,2,0,1,1]
```

As I wanted to use a little more advanced method, I chose to let the user type in the respective coordinates via input:

```
print("Dreieckspunkt A in Koordinatenform (x,y): ")
p1 = input()
print("Dreieckspunkt B in Koordinatenform (x,y): ")
p2 = input()
print("Dreieckspunkt C in Koordinatenform (x,y): ")
p3 = input()
```

Here´s the problem: i am able to cut off the brackets in which the user types the coordinates and create a new list containing only the coordinate figures (via .lstrip , .rstrip , .split(","). Since the input is regarded a string however, I can´t use the content of the list for my calculations. When I tried to format the strings into ints there were always some error messages.

Any suggestions how to solve my issue? Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Please provide a copy of the error messages and/or full stack trace (all the text that python returns upon error)

Comment: first of instead of `lstrip` and `rstrip` use `strip`, what error did you encounter? and `input` always returns a string so you may need to do something like `p1 = int(input())`

Comment: Problem solved, it somehow works now with:
```
For element in l3:
    int_list.append(int(element))
```

Answer (score 0):

Input gives a string. You can use `int(p1)` to convert it to a number, but be aware that if the input is not a number an error will be thrown. You can wrap it in a try-catch block to avoid this

```py
p1 = None
while not p1:
    try:
        p1 = int(input('p1: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Expected a number')

print(2 * p1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn the input into numbers(floats) with `float()`

```
x_values = []
y_values = []

n = 3  # Determines how many values you want user to input
for i in range(n):
    x = float(input("\nEnter x-coordinate: "))
    y = float(input("Enter y-coordinate: "))
    x_values.append(x)
    y_values.append(y)
```

Also note that instead of using `print('Enter num)` and then `input()`. You can just use `input('Enter num')`

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

First, for using `input`, no need to add the `print` statement. You can include that with `input`.

```
p1 = input("Dreieckspunkt A in Koordinatenform (x,y): ")
```

Next, you'll want to split the coordinates on the `,` with `.split(',')`, which will but each input value into a list.

```
p1 = input("Dreieckspunkt A in Koordinatenform (x,y): ").split(',')
```

Like others stated, these will be a string, so you can use list comprehension to convert to an `int` (I'd personally convert to a `float`). Lastly, you can store those 2 values directly.

```
p1 = [float(x) for x in p1]
```

to

```
px1, py1 = [float(x) for x in p1]
```

Put it all together:

```
px1, py1 = [float(x) for x in input("Dreieckspunkt A in Koordinatenform (x,y): ").split(',')]
px2, py2 = [float(x) for x in input("Dreieckspunkt B in Koordinatenform (x,y): ").split(',')]
px3, py3  = [float(x) for x in input("Dreieckspunkt C in Koordinatenform (x,y): ").split(',')]
```

Note: I would probably do a loop like in the solution below, however just wanted to show you it broken down this way as you are learning.